# Webservice does not work after being packaged into a Docker image

Tags: ruby, docker, web

I write a simple webservice in ruby with sinatra. If I run `ruby app.rb` it runs on localhost:4567. I write a Dockerfile to make an image and expose port 4567.

However, when I run the docker image the webservice runs but if I try to connect (with curl and browser) to port 4567, it says `Connection reset by peer`.

Anyone has any suggestion? Because I do not know what to check in this case. I have tried some vague things but still..

The webservice runs normally outside docker.

EDIT 1:

I have pushed the image to `eivor/ruby`. If you run it and go to browser to check it would say `connection reset`. Yes I tried `docker run -p 4567:4567 eivor/ruby` as said before posting the question.

EDIT 2: Here is the `app.rb`

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'referal' # this is the gem that calculate reward points to users
require 'json'
require 'byebug'

get '/' do
  'hello, world!'
end

# inside docker image, even get / returns connection reset by peer
# not to mention post data to it

post '/' do
  data = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
  input = []
  data.each do | key, value |
    input << value
  end
  invs, users = input.reduce([[],[]]) do | results, instruction |
    results = classify(instruction, results[0], results[1])
    results
  end
  res = export(users)
  # byebug
  puts res
end

post '/text' do
  @data = request.body.readlines
  #byebug
  @processed = @data.map{ |s| process(s) }
  @invs, @users = @processed.reduce([[],[]]) do | results, instruction |
    results = classify(instruction, results[0], results[1])
    results
  end
  @jsn = export(@users)
  puts @jsn
end
```

Here is the Dockerfile, i build a lightweight ruby from alpine

```
FROM alpine:3.5
ENV BUILD_PACKAGES bash curl-dev ruby-dev build-base git libstdc++ tzdata ca-certificates
ENV RUBY_PACKAGES ruby>2.3 ruby-irb ruby-rake ruby-io-console ruby-bigdecimal ruby-json

RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add $BUILD_PACKAGES && apk add $RUBY_PACKAGES
RUN apk add ruby-bundler>1.17

RUN echo 'gem: --no-document' > /etc/gemrc && rm -rf /var/cach/apk/*

RUN gem install bundler

RUN mkdir /usr/app
WORKDIR /usr/app
RUN git init

COPY . /usr/app

RUN bundle install

RUN bundle exec rake install

EXPOSE 4567

CMD ["ruby", "./app.rb"]
```

If I run outside docker with command `ruby app.rb` or `bundle exec rerun app.rb` it works normally. But using docker image, it does not. I run the command:

```
docker run -p 4567:4567 eivor/ruby
```

The server runs,

```
[2019-03-14 16:59:59] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2019-03-14 16:59:59] INFO  ruby 2.3.8 (2018-10-18) [x86_64-linux-musl]
== Sinatra (v2.0.5) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2019-03-14 16:59:59] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=4567
```

but when I try to access with browser or curl, it says `connection reset by peer`. If I try to post with curl, the data is actually sent but it does not respond, it hangs up on me instead.

```
curl -v localhost:4567 --data-binary @test/input
```

```
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:4567/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 4567 (#0)
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:4567
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 369
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 369 out of 369 bytes
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Please review how to provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case, a copy of the ```Dockerfile``` and the command line arguments you used to start the container would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I have pushed the docker image and gave my command line.

Comment: Please post your ```Dockerfile``` and ```app.rb``` here so that we may better assist you.

Comment: Hello, I put ```app.rb```, `Dockerfile`, server log and curl log. When I post data with curl, the data is actually sent but the server hangs up on me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is happening because Sinatra by default (development environment) listen on 127.0.0.1 which not works in case of external connection to container

> **:bind** - server hostname or IP address
>
> String specifying the hostname or IP address of the interface to listen on when the :run setting is enabled. The default value in the development environment is 'localhost' which means the server is only available from the local machine. In other environments the default is '0.0.0.0', which causes the server to listen on all available interfaces.

So if you will continue on running in development mode, you need to change it to 0.0.0.0, for example:

```
docker run -p 4567:4567 --name stack eivor/ruby bash -c 'ruby ./app.rb -o 0.0.0.0'
```

Which can be used in Dockerfile as:

```
CMD ["ruby", "./app.rb", "-o", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Or you can use the following within your script:

```
set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
```

Then from outside the container you can get the result:

```
curl -v localhost:4567
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 4567 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:4567
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 13
< X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.3.8/2018-10-18)
< Date: Thu, 14 Mar 2019 17:17:20 GMT
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
hello, world!
```

For more configuration check the following: [CONFIGURING SETTINGS](http://sinatrarb.com/configuration.html)

Comment: okay, this works for the get / method. I still got trouble with posting data to it though. would have to inspect further. but this answers the question. in production, do you use Puma?

Comment: Yes you can depend on puma, unicorn, passenger whatever works for you and also you may use `nginx` in front of your application. For the`POST` method i couldn't try it but it will be an issue related to the code not the communication between your host and docker

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

In few words - try to publish your exposed ports via `-p` argument.

For example:

```
$ docker run -it -p 4567 my-local-image
```

Comment: Yes I did try. If you have more suggestion after this step, I would like to hear.

Comment: Try to see is a service has been started or listen to your connections via:
- `docker ps -a`
- `docker logs {my-container-id}`

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/):

> Flag value    Description
>
> -p 8080:80    Map TCP port 80 in the container to port 8080 on the Docker host.

You need to map the TCP port 4567 in the container to a port on the Docker host. For example, to map it to port 8080:

```
$ docker run -it -p 8080:4567 image-goes-here
```

Comment: Thanks but I did try this. After trying this, do you know what other cue can I check?